# Find Row Number and Column that contain certain values, then insert value into that cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Description: I would like to have a script which finds the row # of Sheet1 that contains a certain value "Cherry" (in column B) and then find the column that contains a certain value "Period 2" (in row 2). Once I have that address (row,column), I would like to insert a value "16" from a certain cell in Sheet2, into Sheet1 at a certain location.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z865gLweziGDwrq1uVc8WmVt4x14kZosJB7CwVG63dY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out:

```
function Update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();
  var dataRange = sheet[0].getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var rowsource = ss.getSheetByName("Budget (Micro)").getRange(6, 1).getValue()
  var columnsource = ss.getSheetByName("Budget (Micro)").getRange(2, 6).getValue()
  var outColumnsource = "PERIOD "+columnsource+""
  Logger.log(outColumnsource)

  var outRow;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    if (values[i][1] == rowsource)
    {
      outRow = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var outColumn;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    if (values[54][i] == outColumnsource)
    {
      outColumn = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }
 
  var location = ss.getSheetByName("Budget (Universal)").getRange(outRow, outColumn)
  var locationsource = ss.getSheetByName("Budget (Micro)").getRange(22, 17).getValue()
  location.setValue(locationsource)
  
  ss.getSheetByName("Budget (Micro)").getRangeList(['E7:E21', 'G7:G21', 'I7:I21']).clearContent()
 
}
```